# How can I loop this question and, in case the user does not type an answer in the command prompt, stop the loop and open a web browser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, loops

I'm new to programming so sorry in advance if this code is a bit messy.

I'm trying to write a program that would prompt the user to type "y" in the command prompt every 5 minutes (the user has 15 seconds to do so), and if the user does not, a browser window would open and play a video in order to wake them up. (link in the code bellow is only an example and not the actual loud sound used to wake the user up)

Currently, the question is only asked once, and then the program closes after 15 seconds have passed.

I've tried to look for what I'm doing wrong online, but I've not been able to understand my mistake.

```
anstoboot = input("Welcome to this short program that will try to make you stay awake! Type start and press enter to start the program")

if(anstoboot == "start" or anstoboot == " start" or anstoboot == "Start" or anstoboot == " Start"):

persontypedno = False

while not persontypedno:
        try:
            persontypednoans = input("Are you awake? (Type y an press enter)")
            time.sleep(15)
            if(persontypednoans == "y" or persontypednoans == " y"):
                time.sleep(15)
                persontypedno = True
        except:
            print("You fell asleep. Please reopen the program")
            webbrowser.open ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcoqR9Bwx1Y", new=1, autoraise=True)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: put a `while True:` around it? - you are _asking_ then _waiting_  ..and nothing will raise an exception- so why the try: except: ? if you type `y` then you wait 30s .... you should think about your controlflow a bit longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using an endless loop which you break if a certain condition is met, after breaking anything outside the loop will be executed, so put your browser launching thing there, if you want the program to keep going after the browser has been opened, enclose everything in another endless loop.

```
# First endless loop to keep restarting everthing
while True:
    # Loop that keeps on going if the user enters something into the input
    while True:

        # Sleep for 5 mins
        time.sleep(300)
        rsp = input("Type something if you are not sleeping yet: ")
        time.sleep(15)

        # Break the current loop if the person hasn't wrote anything
        if len(rsp) <= 0:
            break

    *** code for launching the browser ***
```

Comment: learn what debugging is and just start following your code line by line to see where stuff is going wrong